# Python Error: String indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, types, indices

OK, I have an obvious problems staring me in the face that I can't figure out.  I am getting the output/results I need but I get the TypeError:  "string indices must be integers, not str".  The following is a sample of my code.  It is because of the statement "**if f not in GetSquishySource(dirIn)**"  Basicially I am looking to see if a specific file is in another list so that I don't end up adding it to a zip file I am creating.  I just don't see the problem here and how to get around it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
def compressLists(z, dirIn, dirsIn, filesIn, encrypt=None):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(z, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
            # Add files
            compressFileList(z, dirIn, dirIn, filesIn, zip, encrypt)

            # Add directories
            for dir in dirsIn:
                dirPath = os.path.join(dirIn, dir["name"])
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirPath):
                    # Ignore hidden files and directories
                    files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
                    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d[0] == '.']

                    # Replace file entries with structure value entries
                    for i, f in enumerate(files):
                        del files[i]
                        **if f not in GetSquishySource(dirIn):**
                            files.insert(i, {'zDir': dir["zDir"], 'name': f})

                    compressFileList(z, dirIn, root, files, zip, encryptedLua)
                    if dir["recurse"] == False:
                        break;
```

The following is the GetSquishySource function I created and call.

```
def GetSquishySource(srcDir):
    squishyLines = []
    srcToRemove = []
    if os.path.isfile(srcDir + os.path.sep + "squishy"):
        with open(srcDir + os.path.sep + "squishy") as squishyFile:
            squishyContent = squishyFile.readlines()
        squishyFile.close()

        for line in squishyContent:
            if line.startswith("Module") and line is not None:
                squishyLines.append(line.split(' '))

        for s in squishyLines:
            if len(s) == 3 and s is not None:
                # If the 3rd column in the squishy file contains data, use that.
                path = s[2].replace('Module "', '').replace('"', '').replace("\n", '')
                srcToRemove.append(os.path.basename(path))
            elif len(s) == 2 and s is not None:
                # If the 3rd column in the squishy file contains no data, then use the 2nd column.
                path = s[1].replace('Module "', '').replace('"', '').replace("\n", '').replace(".", os.path.sep) + ".lua"
                srcToRemove.append(os.path.basename(path))

    return srcToRemove
```

Comment: What type is `dir`? What does `dir["zDir"]` do?

Comment: is `dir` a string? It seems you are trying to access it like a dict but from your error it must be a string

Comment: The line below it "files.insert(i, {'zDir': dir["zDir"], 'name': f})" shouldn't have anything to do with it.  If I replace that line with something like "pass" then I still get the TypeError.  But to answer the question, dir is a string.

Comment: try `s = "hello" print (s["ll"]`)

Comment: What's the traceback?

Comment: @user2643864, I don't want you to include that in the code,I want you to run it to show you that you **cannot** use `strings` to `index` `strings`, you need to use `ints` to index a string, `dir[2]` etc.. or `dir[0:4]` to slice first four chars of the string

Comment: Thanks Padraic.  I realize that I need to use ints to index a string, I guess I am just not sure how to get around this issue.

Comment: what exactly is `dir["zDir"]` supposed to be doing, if we know that maybe we can figure a way around it.

Comment: So I am trying to see why you think that is relevant?  The GetSquishySource() method returns a list[] of strings.  I get this error when I am trying to compare if f (iterator above it) is contained in the list I got back from the said function.  You could remove the "files.insert(i, {'zDir': dir["zDir"], 'name': f})" statement and just replace it with something like "pass".

Comment: so the error comes from `GetSquishySource(dirIn)`? Can you add the full traceback also, that will help.

Comment: Here is the traceback.

Comment: ERROR:root:string indices must be integers, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/packager.py", line 64, in CreateFromManifest
    self.ParseXml(xmlRoot, self.srcdir, 0, 0)
  File "C:/packager.py", line 169, in ParseXml
    if not z.compressLists(os.path.join(self.dstdir, zName), root, zDirs, zFiles, zScriptFile):
  File "C:\build_z.py", line 60, in compressLists
    compressFileList(z, dirIn, root, files, zip, encryptedLua)
  File "C:\build_z.py", line 80, in compressFileList
    if file["zDir"] and dir != root:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str